# How to make a univeral Font Awesome mixin with SASS

Tags: unicode, sass, fonts, font-awesome, mixins

I'm trying to make a SASS mixin that lets me specify the mixin call and the Unicode number only. This case is for list items where the icon would show up before the item.

My SASS mixin looks like this. I added both `font-family` options to include everything. If this isn't a good idea, maybe I'll do an `if` statement or something:

```
=faIconBefore($unicode) 
  display: inline-block
  content: "\$unicode"
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Font Awesome 5 Brands"
  font-size: 0.9em
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 900
  font-variant: normal
  color: $colorPrime
  text-rendering: auto
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  margin-right: 0.25em
```

This can be used in code for a download icon like this:

```
+faIconBefore('f019')
```

I've also tried using this in the content line:

```
content: "\#{$unicode}"
```

Ideally, this would just add the icon I wanted, however instead I get `$unicode item.pdf` in my result.

It works fine when hard code the Unicode number into the SASS file, but I can't seem to get this part to work.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to put together a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JeffSydor/jkwnv1go/9/), but it wasn't working at all with the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like that just doesn't work. Maybe using the `@extend` command, but changing the `content` style in the mixin to remove the single quotes and slash ('\') and adding the slash to the Unicode number in the stylesheet seemed to fix it. Here's my new code:

```
// Adding a Font Awesome icon before an element, specifying the unicode number - Usage: +faIconBefore('\f019')
=faIconBefore($unicode)
  display: inline-block
  content: $unicode
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free", "Font Awesome 5 Brands"
  font-size: 0.9em
  font-style: normal
  font-weight: 900
  font-variant: normal
  color: $colorPrime
  text-rendering: auto
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
  margin-right: 0.25em
```

And the usage:

```
+faIconBefore('\f019')
```

If anyone knows of how it could use some refinement, let me know.

Thanks